# Java generics collection doubt

Tags: java, generics, collections

I'm having trouble with a generics. I have defined the following static method:

```
public static <E extends Number> List<E> group(E ... numbers) {
    return Arrays.asList(numbers);
}
```

I understand why this works:

```
List<Integer> ints = group(1, 2, 3);
```

But what do I have to change in my method signature to make this work:

```
List<Number> ints = group(1, 2, 3);
```

Or should I just call the group method specifying the Number type as:

```
List<Number> ints = MyClass.<Number>group(1, 2, 3);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify `Number` as the type argument, as you suggested.

```
List<Number> ints = MyClass.<Number>group(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Another option is to use `List<? extends Number> ints = ...;`

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do get a `List<Number>`.

If your method `group(1,2,3)` return a `List<Integer>`, and you said that worked, so this expression is of type `List<Integer>`.

And `List<Integer>` is *not* a `List<Number>`. Inheritance means specialization, so if your `List<Integer>` would be a kind of `List<Number>` you could add `Double`s to your `List<Integer>` (as the super class can do it, subclass can do it too). And this is wrong.
This not a casting problem, it would just postpone your compile problem to runtime. The problem is logical and quite a paradox for humans, but that's the way collection and inheritance work.

So, if you really want to get a `List<Number>` I suggest you define a second method :

```
public static List<Number> groupAsNumbers(Number ... numbers) {
    return Arrays.asList(numbers);
}
```

Regards, 
 Stéphane

Comment: Just to be clear, in Java `List<Integer>` does not extend `List<Number>`. If your method returns `List<Integer>`, then the correct way to use `Number` as the variable type is `List<? extends Number>`, which tells the compiler that you *really* want a list of items that have `Number` as a base, and not just instances that are statically typed as `Number`.

Comment: Thanks for completion. @Jeremy Heiler. You're right List<? extends Number> is a supertype of both Lists.